# A nice probabilistic problem

Tags: probability

In an exam each student must answer $n$ yes-no questions. We know that no two students have answered all $n$ questions the same. We correspond to each question randomly and uniformly an score between (including) $1$ to $2n$. Show that the probability that only one person has maximum total score is at least $\frac 12$.

Comment: is there any information on the number of students?

Comment: I can show that the probability of only one student having the maximum score is 1 if there are 2^n students.  Should we try to calculate said probability as f(k) for a group of k students?

Comment: @AmireBendjeddou no